# Extracting whole string between two words with special characters using sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed, grep, special-characters

I have a file with each line in the format:

```
<tr><td>20456712 </td><td>Alin Smith </td><td.....(and so on).
```

I want to return all studens names and their ID's in lines, output should be:

```
20456712 Alin Smith
```

.....

How can I do it with sed/grep?.

I've tried many things to get whats between `<tr><td>` and `</td><td>` but nothing worked because of the special characters I think.

I'm already a few days trying with no results.

I've tried => `sed -r 's/.*[<]+tr+[>]+[<]+td+[>](\S+).* <\/td><td>(\S+).*/\1 \2/'`, but it only gave me ID + the first name: `20456712 Alin`

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: last thing I tried
 sed -r 's/.*[<]+tr+[>]+[<]+td+[>](\S+).* <\/td><td>(\S+).*/\1 \2/'

but it only gives me ID + the first name

Comment: Edit your question and insert that line.

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: How about just opening the file with firefox and then copy the displayed table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also help you out:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{8\}\) <\/td><td>\([^<]*\) .*/\1 \2/'
```

[View test on the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsnKA.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this RegEx:

```
<tr><td>([\d\s]+)<\/td><td>([\w\s]+)<\/td>
```

All the data will be stored in **Group 1** (the ID) and **Group 2** (the Full Name). You can see this in the demo by hovering over the match and checing the data in both groups

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3lj)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
<tr>         # Opening <tr>
<td>         # Opening <td>
([\d\s]+)    # ID
<\/td>       # Closing </td>
<td>         # Opening <td>
([\w\s]+)    # Full Name
<\/td>       # Closing </td>
```